# Get data from fragment android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a little problem with my Android app. I have a layout (RelativeLayout) where I place 2 different fragments, and a button that doesn't belong to any of the fragments. The xml code of the activity layout is something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="107dp"
    class="app.fragment1" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="107dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragment1"
    class="app.fragment2" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/btn1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the first fragment (fragment1) I have six EditText controls, where the user has to enter a number in each of the EditText. My question is how can I access the number that has been entered by the users in the EditText controls on the "OnClickListener" method of the button? (on the activity.java file)

Comment: can you post code from java Activity file??

Comment: A very quick approach is to save the data in a static variable. It's messy but serves the purpose. :D

Comment: Have you tried findViewById() method to find your edittexts and gettexts from that?

Comment: You can implement the `onTextChangedListener()` of `EditText` and get the text view into some variable or textview.

Comment: just use findViewById(R.id.your_edittext_id).getText() in your onClickListener, this works because your fragments view is childview of your activity view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of All Give Id to all EditTexts & get all EditTexts via their Ids..look at the below code..

Inside Main Activity...

```
EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
//Do same for All EditTexts

Button button= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             int number = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
             //Do same for All EditTexts
        }
    });
```

Inside Fragment View
you can get button by

```
Button btn = getActivty().findViewById(R.id.btn1);
```

Comment: thank you all for the answers... I'm kind of newbie on Android, and I have messed up with the variable names of the fragment... The solution is what you have posted. Thanks!!

Comment: Your welcome...feel free to ask if you get any problem.